# JavaScript: Fetch text from php and alert

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

quite a noob question, but I tried to use php for the first time and can't get it to work...

I have the most basic php file

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
```

and I try to fetch the output and alert that. Just for learning how to do that...

My JS code (more or less like [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)):

```
fetch('./test.php').then(function(response) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

Both file (test.php and the js file are in the same folder).

Could someone tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks,
celdri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the first comment I got to my answer was correct: It only works on a server/localhost. I seriously didn't know that and I am glad that someone mentioned it! Unfortunately, it seems that the comment has been deleted by some admin. So actually my code was right, I only had to use the absolute path to the php file (though I don't get why)

So php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
```

and JS

```
fetch('./test.php').then(function(response) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
        alert(text);
    });
});
```

work.

Thanks everyone,
celdri

Answer (score 1):

The fetch() method returns a Promise so you can use the then() and catch() methods to handle it:

```
fetch(url)
.then(response => {
    // handle the response
})
.catch(error => {
    // handle the error
});
```

In practice, you often use the async/await with the fetch() method like this:

file 1 : readme.php

```
<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
```

file 2 : fetch.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
async function fetchText() {
    let response = await fetch('./readme.php');

    console.log(response.status); // 200
    console.log(response.statusText); // OK

    if (response.status === 200) {
            let data = await response.text();
            console.log(data);
    }
}

fetchText();
</script>
```

Comment: you can replace console.log(data); with alert(data); to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this.

```
$data = array("data" => $data);
echo json_encode($data);
```

and in js get, i am using axios(https://axios-http.com/docs/intro)
and after console.log(response) and after you can work with response json